# How to run multiple specific RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I've got a huge test suite (> 5000 tests) that take an hour to run. 400 are failing, and I have a list of the failing tests like this:

```
rspec ./spec/models/fullscreen_hidden_view_state_spec.rb:116 # FullscreenHiddenViewState showing a playlist on third element - slide has all the right links and properties
rspec ./spec/features/fullscreen/play_spec.rb:59 # View case in fullscreen presention mode Courtesy section when viewing the cases discussion via the cases hidden share token the Add To button should be hidden
rspec ./spec/features/cases/index_spec.rb:204 # finding a case Filtering by study modality Filtering by modality only shows cases with modality
rspec ./spec/models/playlist_spec.rb[1:2:2:2:1] # Playlist it should behave like an entity with privacy .by_privilege (Playlist examples) for annonymous contains public playlists
rspec ./spec/models/playlist_spec.rb[1:2:2:2:2] # Playlist it should behave like an entity with privacy .by_privilege (Playlist examples) for annonymous works
rspec ./spec/models/playlist_spec.rb[1:2:2:3:1] # Playlist it should behave like an entity with privacy .by_privilege (Playlist examples) for privileged user contains all playlists
rspec ./spec/models/playlist_spec.rb[1:2:2:1:1] # Playlist it should behave like an entity with privacy .by_privilege (Playlist examples) for unprivileged users contains public and the users unlisted playlists
rspec ./spec/models/playlist_spec.rb[1:2:2:1:2] # Playlist it should behave like an entity with privacy .by_privilege (Playlist examples) for unprivileged users works
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:1004 # User quotas limited_unlisted_cases? user with manage cases privilege should equal false
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:813 # User quotas #can_add_draft_case? when non-deleted draft case count above the limit for privileged user should equal true
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:920 # User quotas #allowed_draft_cases user with manage cases privilege should eq -1
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:962 # User quotas allowed_unlisted_playlists user with manage cases privilege should eq -1
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:861 # User quotas allowed_unlisted_cases user with manage cases privilege should eq -1
```

I know I can run each line to run the specific tests, but is there an easy way to run all of them?

Comment: are you asking how to run all of them at once? if yes, you can do `bundle exec rake` or `bundle exec rspec` from the root directory

Comment: Just skip the failing ones by using `xit` or any other.

Comment: @Subash I have thousands of tests, I don't want to run all of them, just all the ones that failed on a previous `bundle exec rspec`

Comment: If you run the specs locally, then you can run with `--only-failures` or better `--next-failure`

Comment: see this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/61382138/3437900

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to run your specs for multiple files:

```
rspec path/to/first/file path/to/second/file
```

Comment: will this reload rspec for each test? Because that might take hours with the number of tests I've got, and will print the test results after each test instead of at the end of all of them

Comment: awesome! That's what I was looking for. Is there a way to have each test on a separate line in the script?

Comment: @Mirror318 it runs them in the same suite

Answer (score 8):

You could use the rspec [`--only-failures`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/only-failures) option which will only load and run spec files with failures.

**Update:** As @Grzegorz mentioned in the comments, you have to run all of them first and this command will give the failures from the last run.

Comment: For the record - you need to run them all first for this command to work, and the question doesn't state that. He could have those fails from the CI server.

Comment: Yes this is a cool feature, but you need to run the full test suit first (takes a long time)

Answer (score 3):

> FYI, might not answer this question exactly but it's expected to help other visitors with similar queries.

## Multiple files with pattern

If you wish to run spec from some specific folders then you might use

```
rspec --pattern=./spec/features/**/*_spec.rb
```

If you want to exclude some files

```
rspec --pattern=./spec/features/**/*_spec.rb --exclude-pattern="./spec/features/{folder1,folder2}/**/*_spec.rb"
```

see this for more info https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/command-line/pattern-option

#### Multiple files starting with some char or phrase

```
rspec --pattern="./spec/features/[t]*_spec.rb"
```

Here, it will run all specs with filename starting with `t`.

```
rspec --pattern="./spec/features/[tran|u]*_spec.rb"
```

Here, it will run all specs with filename starting with `tran` or `u`.

to learn more, visit [How to run multiple spec files in RSpec using single command in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562680/run-rspec-for-multiple-files-in-one-go)