# How to run multiple spec files in RSpec using single command in terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I need to run RSpec at one go for multiple files of my choice can anyone guide me through it? I am a beginner so please explain clearly

Comment: [Check this answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48778429/8267417)

Comment: have you tried with https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run multiple specific RSpec tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778373/how-to-run-multiple-specific-rspec-tests)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

## For multiple files without a pattern

You can use the following syntax to run your specs for multiple files:

```
rspec path/to/first/file path/to/second/file
```

---

## Multiple files with pattern

If you wish to run spec from some specific folders then you might use

```
rspec --pattern=./spec/features/**/*_spec.rb
```

If you want to exclude some files

```
rspec --pattern=./spec/features/**/*_spec.rb --exclude-pattern="./spec/features/{folder1,folder2}/**/*_spec.rb"
```

see this for more info https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/command-line/pattern-option

#### Multiple files starting with some char or phrase

```
rspec --pattern="./spec/features/[t]*_spec.rb"
```

Here, it will run all specs with filename starting with `t`.

```
rspec --pattern="./spec/features/[tran|u]*_spec.rb"
```

Here, it will run all specs with filename starting with `tran` or `u`.

---

## For running the failing tests only

You can use the `rspec --only-failures` option which will only load and run spec files with failures.